# Hiding PyQt main window affects behaviour of child dialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qdialog, qmessagebox

In PyQt5, I'm wondering why hiding a QMainWindow affects the behaviour of child dialogs?

For example, in the code below, if I click "Show dialog" -> "OK", the QMessageBox is displayed then the program terminates. However, if I comment out the self.hide() and self.show() in showChildDialog(), the program returns to showing the child dialog after the QMessageBox is displayed.

Ideally, I would like the program to return to the child dialog after displaying the QMessageBox, but I also want to hide the main window while the child dialog is displayed.

How can I achieve both behaviours simultaneously?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class mainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

       self.dialog = childDialog(self)

       self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')

       self.buttonShow = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
       self.buttonShow.setText("Show Dialog")
       self.buttonShow.clicked.connect(self.showChildDialog)

   def showChildDialog(self):
       self.hide()                 # works as intended if this commented out...
       self.dialog.exec()
       self.show()                 # and this.


class childDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(childDialog, self).__init__(parent)

       self.buttonOk = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
       self.buttonOk.setText("OK")
       self.buttonOk.clicked.connect(self.ok_clicked)

       self.buttonHide = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
       self.buttonHide.setText("Close")
       self.buttonHide.clicked.connect(self.hide_clicked)

       self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
       self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonOk)
       self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonHide)

   def hide_clicked(self):
       self.accept()

   def ok_clicked(self):
       # do somehting here that causes an error
       dialog = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(text='an error occurred')
       dialog.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys

   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   app.setApplicationName('myWindow')

   main = mainWindow()
   main.show()

   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: By "the program terminates", I wouldn't be surprised if it crashed. Does it make a difference if you don't give it a parent?

Comment: I just mean terminates with exit code 0, whereas I want the program to return to the child dialog (e.g. so the user can rectify what causes the input error tht would be described in the QMessageBox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change this line:

```
self.dialog = childDialog(self)
```

to this line:

```
self.dialog = childDialog()
```

it works properly.

Comment: Yes this works thank you (also thank you to @Peter). I have also, found that setting the QMessageBox parent to self resolves the problem.

Comment: @TonyJones setting the parent for dialogs is almost always the right choice, as it allows better control over the hierarchy also from the Qt side: the issue here is related to the fact that you're using *nested* event loops (the application, the child dialog, the message box). As you already found out, the *proper* solution is to set the parent for *both* dialogs. Also note that in complex cases you should prefer using [`open()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#open) instead of `exec()`, and connect the signals accordingly. Also remember to set the `WA_DeleteOnClose` for "on the fly" dialogs.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for the explanation and tips. May I ask, if setting parents for all dialogs as you suggest, why and how I should be setting the `WA_DeleteOnClose`?

Comment: @TonyJones Whenever a QDialog is created with a parent, that dialog will be persistent until it's *explicitly* destroyed. If not, it will exist in the memory until the program quits. While in normal conditions this is not usually an issue (especially considering the amount of RAM of modern computers), this is still a flaw: if the program keeps running for a lot of time and many dialogs are shown, memory usage will constantly increase. When a temporary dialog is being created, it should have a `Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute set, unless proper fail-safes are being used in order to destroy it.